# Adding multiple UI in one project using devexpress

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I tried to find out the answer but no appropriate answer.... so hopefully developer community on stack will help me out.

I have already developed application using devexpress and having Office Inspired UI (https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114442/build-an-application/choose-application-ui/office-inspired-ui) but for few forms we would like to use another UI Touch Enabled UI (https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114443/build-an-application/choose-application-ui/touch-enabled-tile-ui) Is it possible to have two different UI in same project? If yes what should be the procedure.

Comment: Yes, it's possible (two seperate forms, setting which determines which UI to use and handling the openening of the appropriate form in Program.cs. But it's a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple UIs in the same project. Most of the items in the documentation you linked to are available as individual controls which can be dropped onto any form. Additionally, if your form inherits from XtraForm or RibbonForm, you can set the LookAndFeel.TouchUIMode property to DefaultBoolean.True, forcing the form and its child controls to use the touch scale factor:

```
this.LookAndFeel.TouchUIMode = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
```